# how to define a function to use it later in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In plain Javascript, it is pretty easy to define a function then call it later, but I am still new to Jquery, can you help me out?

below is Plain Javascript, but I want to do this with Jquery

```html
<script>
function displayMe(){document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Display"};
</script>

<button type="button" onclick="displayMe()">
    Click me to add the word "Display" to the page.
</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

then here a working Jquery, but not what i want to do,

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#displayMe').click(function(){
        $("#demo").html('Display');
    });
});
</script>

<button type="button" id="displayMe">
    Click me to add the word "Display" to the page.
</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

and now my attempt to define and use later

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
<script>
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#displayMe').click(displayfunction(){ });
});

function displayFunction (){
    $("#demo").html('Display')
};
</script>

<button type="button" id="displayMe">
    Click me to add the word "Display" to the page.
</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

it shows the error in:

```
{
  "message": "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 20,
  "colno": 41
}
```

i have tried to add )'s, just get other errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just supply the function's name to the `click` handler, and the name is `displayFunction`, not `displayfunction`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#displayMe').click(displayFunction);
});

function displayFunction() {
  $("#demo").html('Display')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" id="displayMe">
Click me to add the word "Display" to the page.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Or, simply use the `onclick` attribute like you did in your first example:

```js
function displayFunction() {
  $("#demo").html('Display')
};
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha256-pasqAKBDmFT4eHoN2ndd6lN370kFiGUFyTiUHWhU7k8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button type="button" id="displayMe" onclick="displayFunction()">
Click me to add the word "Display" to the page.</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass `displayFunction` as a parameter for `$('#displayMe').click()`

```js
function displayFunction() {
    $("#demo").html('Display')
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#displayMe').click(displayFunction);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="displayMe">
 Click me to add the word "Display" to the page.
</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```